# as3 downloading content from server to application directory?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, download, directory

```
import flash.filesystem.*;
/// Change the line below to point to your mp3 online
var urlString:String = "http://edvizenor.com/upload/php/files/trust.mp3";
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(urlString);
var urlStream:URLStream = new URLStream();
var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
urlStream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loaded);
urlStream.load(urlReq);

function loaded(event:Event):void
{
    urlStream.readBytes(fileData, 0, urlStream.bytesAvailable);
    writeAirFile();
}

function writeAirFile():void
{ 
    // Change the folder path to whatever you want plus name your mp3
    // If the folder or folders does not exist it will create it.
```

**HERE ARE THE LINES I NEED HELP WITH:**

```
var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("Yahoo.mp3");// WORKS
var file:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("Yahoo.mp3"); // NO WORK
```

I need to get THIS SECOND LINE to save to the directory it is stored in. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
    fileStream.close();
    trace("The file is written.");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To save In application directory. 
Use

```
var file:File = File.userDirectory.resolvePath("Yahoo.mp3");// WORKS
var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("Yahoo.mp3"); // It will work


var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
fileStream.writeBytes(fileData, 0, fileData.length);
fileStream.close();
trace("The file is written.");
```

}

Because application directory is the package directory of your application.

Comment: Will this also work on an iphone? Will it be the correct path?

Comment: I haven't test it on iphone. but it should defiantly work. You can give a try to it.

Comment: It does work on an iPhone and droid but to call the file once saved you have to use this code: I will use an mp3 example. mySound.load(new URLRequest("file://"+File.applicationStorageDirectory.nativePath+"/YourSong.mp3"));